# CodeIgniter mail not working on server but works fine localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

i am using Shared hosting plan. I tried my level best but i am not able to resolve this issue. 
here is my code. i tried first with gmail but was not working then i read somewhere that may the IP of my shared hosting plan is blacklisted by google then i tired my own smtp then imap server, same results it works fine on localhost but again i am getting the same error.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Contact extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -  
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();   
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
    }   
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('security');
        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_space_only');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Emaid ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        //run validation on form input
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //validation fails
        $this->load->view('head');
        $this->load->view('map');
        $this->load->view('footer_map');
        }

        else
        {
            //get the form data
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
            $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');

            //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
            $to_email = 'example@gmail.com';

            //configure email settings
            $config['protocol'] = 'imap';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'imap.example.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'info@exampl.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'example';
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
            $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
           // $this->load->library('email', $config);


            $this->email->initialize($config); 
            //send mail
            $this->email->from($from_email, $name);
            $this->email->to($to_email);
            $this->email->reply_to($from_email, $name);
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($message);


            if ($this->email->send())
            {
                // mail sent
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
                redirect('contact/index');
            }
            else
            {
                //error
                echo $this->email->print_debugger();
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
                redirect('contact/index');
            }
        }

    }
    public function alpha_space_only($str)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$str))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_space_only', 'The %s field must contain only alphabets and space');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

i am getting this output

```
There is error in sending mail! Please try again later.
```

Help me guys, i m tired

Comment: Some mail servers on shared systems won't allow you to send email unless the From address is an address on that domain. So if you're website is example.com, the From must be something@example.com. Try setting that, and set the sender's email address as the Reply To.

Answer (score 0):

On line 73 of the code you posted it looks like the if statement for

```
$this->email->send()
```

is failing, which then runs this:

```
  else
  {
        //error
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
        redirect('contact/index');
  }
```

I would check the configuration in Email.php - in my Codeigniter 3 project it is located here:

```
html/system/libraries/Email.php
```

At the bottom of [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) Codeigniter 3 API page is some info about print_debugger and about the Email library.  It should help you get in the right direction.